# How to uninclude sass mixin

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I've this mixin applied on a menu, I don't want see on small resolution:

```
@mixin visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```

This working fine. But on bigger resolution I will show this menu. Obviously I can restyle and revert these attributes (I'm allready done it). But I was thinking if is there some built-in way to remove mixins – something like `@uninclude visuallyhidden;`.

Or is there a better way how to do this?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries to only apply the styles when appropriate.  Doing and undoing bloats your CSS unnecessarily.

```
@media (max-width: 45em) {
    .foo {
        @include visuallyhidden();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using SASS named breakpoint so I can use `@include respond-to(between phone and tablet){…}`. So there is no built-in way how to revert a mixin?

Comment: No.  Sass doesn't know what you've already set.  If you want to undo it, you have to do it yourself (either by hand or create a corresponding mixin to what you've already got).